# NSData dataWithContentsOfFile "No such File or Directory" when trying to read in a public key

Tags: ios, ios7, nsdata, public-key-encryption

The error is very clear but I don't think its accurate.
These are the steps.

1. I have a public.key file on my hard drive and I copy this into the Supporting Files directory
2. add following code:

   NSMutableString *path;
   path = [[NSMutableString *] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
   [path appendString@"/public.key"]
   NSData *publicKey = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options:nil error:&error];

Running this code generates:

`a file not found exception.`

ok.
So I repeat the same process this time with a image file

```
NSMutableString *path;
path = [[NSMutableString *] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
[path appendString@"/image.jpg"]
NSData *publicKey = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options:nil error:&error];
```

And now this works.
So I am sure the path is correct.
If I try rename the public.key to something else then this still does not work.
Is it because maybe the .key file is like a binary file ?
So what possible reasons are preventing me from reading in public.key to NSData ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this NSBundle method `-URLForResource: withExtension:`? Have you checked your app bundle? Does it really contains `public.key` file? Maybe the error is correct and this file isn't presented in app bundle.